# PDO DATE_SUB() to filter data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

There is a table with a colunm to store datetime (format: 2014-5-5 9:21pm). I'm using PDO to get data from this table within 60 days compairing the datetime colunm value. My query doe not respond. CAN someone tell me what's wrong?

```
foreach ($myCon->query("SELECT * FROM students_tbl LEFT OUTER JOIN fees_tbl ON students_tbl.username = fees_tbl.studentname WHERE exec_datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(students_tbl.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i%p'),INTERVAL '60' DAY)") as $results){
echo $results['grade'];
}
```

Comment: 1. If you had `error_reporting` turned on you'd see an error about trying to use a boolean value in a foreach because 2. You should be checking the return value of `query()` since it will return `false` when the query fails to execute because 3. You're not using the correct syntax for `BETWEEN`. See @James's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

correct BETWEEN syntax:

```
somedate BETWEEN date1 and date2
```

what you have:

```
somedate BETWEEN date1
```

Comment: Also ensure you put min date first, then max date.